# Event Snippet Google Ad Conversion Tracking Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ecommerce-tracking, conversion, google-adwords

I am trying to figure out how to get **Google Ad conversion tracking** working in **Magento 2.3.5** - the Google Ad API setting isn't available under admin area of this version. Universal Tracking Code already installed on every page.

So far I've added the following to the **success.phtml** file:

```
<?php
$OrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$Order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderId);
$incrementId = $Order->getIncrementId();
?>

<!-- Event snippet for Purchase conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX',
      'value': <?php echo number_format($Order->getSubtotal(),2,".",""); ?>,
      'currency': 'GBP',
      'transaction_id': <?php echo "'".$incrementId."'"; ?>
  });
</script>
```

I think the above code *may* work for Magento 1. Can anyone suggest an update for Magento 2?

Comment: Do have any custom module in your magento ? default Adword code does not have `transaction_id` from block class.

Comment: I've had to use the script above myself, as the 'Adword' section does not appear in the Magento admin (Store > Configuration > Sales > Google API) of this 2.3.5 store.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento Devdocs Google AdWords](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/google-adwords.html)

```
<!-- Google Code for Back to School Sale Conversion Page -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
   var google_conversion_id = 999999999;
   var google_conversion_language = "en";
   var google_conversion_format = "3";
   var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
   var google_conversion_label = "MlEYCOKBnGoQz6CZoAM";
   var google_remarketing_only = false;
   /* ]]> */
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
   </script>
   <noscript>
   <div style="display:inline;">
   <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/872829007/?label=MlEYCOKBnGoQz6CZoAM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>

   </noscript>
```

Comment: Add that in success.phtml do you think? With the relevant conversion id?